# Func callback using objects not in parameter list of Func in regards to memory leaks in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, memory-leaks, func

I have a callback function below that takes one parameter of `name`. I have some others that come from the calling parent function.  Are the parameters `otherGame`, `_venueLocationsManager`, etc going to cause any type of memory leaks or performance problems or is this a valid programming setup?

```
private IEnumerable<ValidateScheduleResult> GetMinimumOverlappingPoolGames(EventScheduleGameLayout gridItem, EventScheduleGameLayout otherGame, EventScheduleTeamLayout otherTeam, int minimumTimeBetweenGames, ValidationScheduleSettingsModel scheduleSettings)
        {
            Func<string, ValidateScheduleResult> callback = (name) =>
            {
                return FillGameInformation(new ValidateMinimumTimeBetweenGamesResult(name, otherGame.GetDate(), otherGame.GetTime(), _venueLocationsManager.GetVenueLocationName(otherGame.VenueCourtId), minimumTimeBetweenGames, scheduleSettings.ContestType), gridItem, ValidateItemResult.StatusType.Warning);
            };

            return GetOverlappingPoolGames(gridItem, otherTeam, callback);
        }
```

**Callback From**

```
private IEnumerable<ValidateScheduleResult> GetOverlappingPoolGames(EventScheduleGameLayout gridItem, EventScheduleTeamLayout otherTeam, Func<string, ValidateScheduleResult> callback)
        {
            var validationScheduleResults = new List<ValidateScheduleResult>();

            Action<string> nameCallback = (name) =>
            {
                validationScheduleResults.Add(callback(name));
            };

            _eventScheduleValidatorsService.PoolGamesValidator.IsPoolGamesRestricted(gridItem.Matchup.AwayTeam, otherTeam, nameCallback);
            _eventScheduleValidatorsService.PoolGamesValidator.IsPoolGamesRestricted(gridItem.Matchup.HomeTeam, otherTeam, nameCallback);
            if (gridItem.Matchup.WorkTeam != null)
            {
                _eventScheduleValidatorsService.PoolGamesValidator.IsPoolGamesRestricted(gridItem.Matchup.WorkTeam, otherTeam, nameCallback);
            }

            foreach (var validationResult in validationScheduleResults)
                yield return validationResult;
        }
```

**Calling Code**

```
if (scheduleSettings.MinimumTimeBetweenGames.HasValue)
                        {
                            // Get Division Teams And Teams Cross Playing
                            var minimumTimesBetween = GetMinimumTimeBetweenRow(scheduledMatchups, scheduleSettings.MinimumTimeBetweenGames.Value, gridItem.GameDuration, gridItem).Where(q => q != gridItem && (q.Matchup.DivisionId == gridItem.Matchup.DivisionId || ScheduleHelper.HasTeamGame(q.Matchup, gridItem.Matchup) || ScheduleHelper.HasSeededGame(q.Matchup, gridItem.Matchup))).ToList();

                            foreach (var divisionGame in minimumTimesBetween)
                            {
                                validationResults.AddRange(GetMinimumOverlappingPoolGames(gridItem, divisionGame, divisionGame.Matchup.AwayTeam, scheduleSettings.MinimumTimeBetweenGames.Value, scheduleSettings));
                                validationResults.AddRange(GetMinimumOverlappingPoolGames(gridItem, divisionGame, divisionGame.Matchup.HomeTeam, scheduleSettings.MinimumTimeBetweenGames.Value, scheduleSettings));
                            }
                        }
```

**IsPoolGameRestricted**

```
 public bool IsPoolGamesRestricted(
            EventScheduleTeamLayout currentTeam,
            EventScheduleTeamLayout otherTeam,
            Action<string> nameCallback)
        {
nameCallback?.Invoke(FormatGameName.GetPoolName(currentTeam.PoolNumber, currentTeam.PoolName));
                return true;
            }
```

Comment: It's very difficult to base that on just the code snippet that you've shared here. Could you update your example with the function it's calling as well as the code where you'll be calling this callback from?

Comment: Hopefully this extra code makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not cause any memory leaks, because the .NET Runtime will manage memory allocation for you and will ensure these objects won't be cleaned as long as they are still in use.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/

For performance using a call-back versus calling the function directly should be pretty similar, if not the same.

As a side-note, instead of relying on callbacks for deferred execution, you may also want to take a look at using [async/await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) which offers an alternative, and arguably easier to read solution.

Comment: Unfortunately the site has sync functions everywhere and converting that to async would be a nightmare.

Comment: If it's not feasible to upgrade your entire code-base to use asynchronous calls, an intermediate solution could be to use `Task.RunSynchronously()` to call into asynchronous functions from synchronous ones. This would allow you to migrate the tricky bits to async without committing to it for the whole application.

Comment: Doesnt that take up extra threads in IIS?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.runsynchronously?view=net-5.0) the Task will be executed on the calling thread.